# método JSON.stringify()

Tags: javascript, json

Tenho uma dúvida sobre o método `JSON.stringify()`.

Realizando a consulta desses valores em uma tebela de membro:

```
{
    "NProjetos": [
        {
            "idProjeto": 2,
            "nomeProjetos": "SGI"
        }
    ],
    "cargo": "Desenvolvedor",
    "descricao": "Desenvolvedor PHP, JAVA",
    "id": 2,
    "imgMembros": [
        {
            "idImg": 2,
            "url": "img/diego.png"
        }
    ],
    "nome": "Diego Rabelo",
    "stats": 3
};
```

Com

```
JSON.stringify(membro.NProjetos, ['nomeProjetos']); //retorno:  [{"nomeProjetos":"SGI"}]

JSON.stringify(membro.nomeProjetos); //não tem retorno.
```

Como eu poderia pegar só o valor, no caso "SGI"?

Comment: E essa aspa dupla faltando em `"NProjetos"`? Foi erro na hora de escrever a pergunta ou tá errado no código?

Comment: Não é um JSON válido, primeiro você pode testar por aqui: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Aliás, o que é **`membro`** em `JSON.stringify(membro.nomeProjetos)`? Aparentemente sua dúvida é simples, mas não dá pra entender o que você quer.

Comment: Erro de digitação mesmo, Jbueno.

Comment: Acredito que se seu interesse for pegar somente o valor, você pode simplesmente usar: `var nomeProj = membro.NProjetos[0].nomeProjetos`, do que fazer stringify.

Comment: Pelo que entendi é isso também @LucasCosta, mas minha dúvida é,Ítalo, podem vir `N` projetos certo? você quer o `nomeProjetos` de todos?

Comment: Baseado no JSON https://jsfiddle.net/lbclucascosta/5n8wdtmg/

Comment: Obrigado, Lucas. É isso mesmo Kenny.

Answer (score 1):

Se queres obter um JSON ou um array com todos os valores de `"nomeProjetos "` dentro de `"NProjetos"` basta mapeares essa array assim:

```
var nProjetos = membro.NProjetos.map(el => el.nomeProjetos);
```

ou em JavaScript menos moderno:

```
var nProjetos = membro.NProjetos.map(function(el){
    return el.nomeProjetos
});
```

e depois para criar um JSON:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(nProjetos);
```

**Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/jw3mgwms/**

Answer (score 0):

Sendo `membro` o seu Json descrito na pergunta, você deve pegar primeiramente os valores. O problema não é especificamente no método `JSON.stringify()`

```
var projetos = []

for(var i = 0 ; i < membro.NProjetos.length ; i++){
    projetos.push(membro.NProjetos[i].nomeProjetos)
}
```

Ou, se estiver usando JQuery

```
var projetos = []

$.each(membro.NProjetos, function(){
    projetos.push($(this).nomeProjetos);
});
```

Se preferir pode usar `map` também do JQuery

```
var projetos = []

$.map(membro.NProjetos, function(projeto, i){
   projetos.push(projeto.nomeProjetos);
});
```

Com isso, você terá um array `projetos`, onde terá o nome de todos os projetos do seu Json.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode mapear os nomes dos projetos em um novo array usango o [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var projetosMembros = membros.NProjetos.map(proj => {
  return proj.nomeProjetos;
});
```

```js
var membros = {"NProjetos": [{"idProjeto": 2,"nomeProjetos": "SGI"}],"cargo": "Desenvolvedor","descricao": "Desenvolvedor PHP, JAVA","id": 2,"imgMembros": [{"idImg": 2,"url": "img/diego.png"}],"nome": "Diego Rabelo","stats": 3};

var projetosMembros = membros.NProjetos.map(proj => {
  return proj.nomeProjetos;
});

console.log(projetosMembros);
```

Com laço clássico de repetição (ECMA5):

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < membros.NProjetos.length ; i++){
    projetosMembros.push(membros.NProjetos[i].nomeProjetos);
}
```

```js
var membros = {"NProjetos": [{"idProjeto": 2,"nomeProjetos": "SGI"}],"cargo": "Desenvolvedor","descricao": "Desenvolvedor PHP, JAVA","id": 2,"imgMembros": [{"idImg": 2,"url": "img/diego.png"}],"nome": "Diego Rabelo","stats": 3};

var projetosMembros = [];
for (var i = 0 ; i < membros.NProjetos.length ; i++){
    projetosMembros.push(membros.NProjetos[i].nomeProjetos);
}

console.log(projetosMembros);
```

Answer (score 0):

dado o objeto

```
membro = {
    "NProjetos": [
        {
            "idProjeto": 2,
            "nomeProjetos": "SGI"
        }
    ],
    "cargo": "Desenvolvedor",
    "descricao": "Desenvolvedor PHP, JAVA",
    "id": 2,
    "imgMembros": [
        {
            "idImg": 2,
            "url": "img/diego.png"
        }
    ],
    "nome": "Diego Rabelo",
    "stats": 3
};
```

`JSON.stringify()` serve para transformar o JSON em uma stringy mas pelo que entendi de sua duvida vc não quer fazer isso, vc apenas usou pois não sabia outro modo de pegar o conteúdo

Explicação do porque o codigo não funcionou como você queria
`JSON.stringify(membro.nomeProjetos); //não tem retorno.` 
ao digitar membro.nomeProjetos você esta acessando a variavel membro ( que é o objeto json) e logo em seguida tentou usar o objeto nomeProjetos porem esse objeto não existe neste nivel vc deve entrar primeiro em Nprojetos  depois acessar o array e depois acessar o elemento  nomeProjetos

creio eu que vc queria fazer o seguinte .....

```
newJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(membro.NProjetos[0])) //Cria um novo json como se fosse (em toscamente) um subConjunto de membro
newJson.nomeProjetos // acessa
```

ou acessar direto

```
membro['NProjetos'][0]['nomeProjetos']
//ou
membro.NProjetos[0].nomeProjetos
```

Answer (score 0):

Entendi sua pergunta e tenho a solução **correta**.

No entanto, não sei se quer fazer isso por falta de opção ou conhecimento.

Por isso, trago duas soluções:

- Aquela que responde sua pergunta;
- Aquela que simplifica sua vida.

**respondendo sua pergunta**

Segundo a [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

> O método `JSON.stringify()` converte um objeto ou valor JavaScript, em uma string JSON. **Opcionalmente** substitui valores, se uma **função de substituição** é passada ou, opcionalmente, converte somente propriedades especificadas em uma **array de substituição**.

A array de substituição nada mais é que uma lista, onde você coloca o nome de cada propriedade que deseja incluir na conversão.

```js
let selecionado
let humano;

humano = {
  nome: "José",
  idade: 33,
  altura: "1.8m"
}

// output: {"nome":"José","idade":33}
selecionado = JSON.stringify(humano, ["nome", "idade"]);
console.log(selecionado);

// output: {"nome":"José"}
selecionado = JSON.stringify(humano, ["nome"]);
console.log(selecionado);
```

Já a [função de substituição](https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/filter.php), é um callback que recebe dois argumentos: um com o nome do objeto e outro com o valor.

Essa função pode usar os argumentos para modificar ou filtrar o valor.

Quando a função retorna `undefined`, o valor é filtrado (removido da conversão).

Quando a função retorna algo diferente de `undefined`, este valor é utilizado na conversão.

```js
let substituido
let humano;

humano = {
  nome: "José",
  idade: 44,
  altura: "1.8m"
}

function substituicao(name, value) {

  if (value.idade != 44) return undefined

  return `${value.idade}`
}

// output: "José"
substituido = JSON.stringify(humano, (name, value) => value.nome);
console.log(substituido);

// output: 66
substituido = JSON.stringify(humano, substituicao);
console.log(substituido);
```

Desse modo, a solução para sua pergunta seria essa:

```js
let projetos,
membro;

function substituicao(name, projetos) {

  let nomes;

  nomes = projetos.map(projeto => projeto.nomeProjetos);
  nomes = nomes.join(", ");

  return nomes;
}

membro = {
  "NProjetos": [
  {
      "idProjeto": 2,
      "nomeProjetos": "SGI"
  }
  ],
  "cargo": "Desenvolvedor",
  "descricao": "Desenvolvedor PHP, JAVA",
  "id": 2,
  "imgMembros": [
  {
      "idImg": 2,
      "url": "img/diego.png"
  }
  ],
  "nome": "Diego Rabelo",
  "stats": 3
};

projetos = JSON.stringify(membro.NProjetos, substituicao);
console.log(projetos);
```

**simplificando a vida**

Se você não precisa converter o objeto em string, antes de filtrar os nomes de projetos, poderias mapeá-los deste modo:

```js
let nomes;

membro = {
  "NProjetos": [
  {
      "idProjeto": 2,
      "nomeProjetos": "SGI"
  }
  ],
  "cargo": "Desenvolvedor",
  "descricao": "Desenvolvedor PHP, JAVA",
  "id": 2,
  "imgMembros": [
  {
      "idImg": 2,
      "url": "img/diego.png"
  }
  ],
  "nome": "Diego Rabelo",
  "stats": 3
};

projetos = membro.NProjetos.map(projeto => projeto.nomeProjetos);
nomes = projetos.join(", ");

console.log(nomes);
```